# .toggle() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT:

I have changed to the following but still doesn't work:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.hide').hide();
    $('#bio1 a').click(function()
    {
      //Change case studies
      $('#more1').toggle('slow');
    });
```

---

For some reason my jquery toggle function doesn't work, although the .hide() function does. I'm not sure what is the problem, any suggestions welcome!

HTML:

```
                <h3><a>Some dude</a></h3>
                <p>SOME TEXT
                    <br> <div id="bio1">  <a href="" > <i > <b> Read More </b> </i> </a> <br></div>
                    <div class="hide" id="more1"> SOME TEXT.</p></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(.hide).hide();
        $('#bio1').click(function()
        {
          $('#more1').toggle(slow);
        });    
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably receive this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

The reason is because of `$(.hide)`. You need to wrap the class name in quotes `$('.hide')`.

Secondly, you'll get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: slow is not defined
```

The reason is because of `.toggle(slow)`. Since `slow` is not a variable so again you need to wrap it inside in quotes `'.toggle('slow')'`

Final code should look like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.hide').hide();
// -- ^     ^ add this
    $('#bio1').click(function()
    {
      $('#more1').toggle('slow');
      // ----            ^    ^ add this
    });    
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UAC7B/)**

Comment: Also 'slow' is a string which should be wrapped in quotes, unless you have defined a variable e.g. `var slow=100;` somewhere else. Then make sure your div #bio1 actually has a clickable height or attach the event to `$('#bio1 a')`

Answer (score 1):

Qoutation is missing here:

```
$(.hide).hide();
```

It would be:

```
$('.hide').hide();
```

and then the parameter to be changed too:

```
$('slow') // or time in milliseconds..
```

Answer (score 1):

Put some quotes areound the `slow` otherwise it will generate errors `$('#more1').toggle("slow");`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

1. `$(.hide).hide();`is wrong. It has to be `$('.hide').hide();`
2. `$('#more1').toggle(slow);`- slow is not defined.

Try this.

```
$('#bio1').click(function(){
    $('#more1').toggle();   
});
```

***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/Ps6YG/)***